# Responsividade em dispositivos móveis com bootstrap-material?

Tags: css, mobile, layout-responsivo

Estou usando `bootstrap-material`em um sistema, caso eu use o navegador não maximizado a responsividade funciona. Porém em dispositivos móveis não. Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

[image: Aqui com o navegador em modo janela]

[image: Aqui em dispositivo móvel]

---

> Estilos

```
<link href="{{ elixir('css/all.css') }}" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/resources/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/bootstrap-material-design.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/resources/bootstrap-material-design/dist/css/ripples.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/resources/bootstrap-material-design/dist/sassc/ripples.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="/resources/bootstrap-material-design/dist/sassc/bootstrap-material-design.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

---

> Scripts

```
<script src="/resources/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="/resources/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="{{ elixir('js/all.js') }}"></script>
<script src="/resources/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/material.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/resources/bootstrap-material-design/dist/js/ripples.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

---

Existe algum outro css que preciso importar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Esse problema é resolvido utilizando a **META TAG** `viewport`.

**Descrição básica:**
O viewport é a área onde seu website aparece

Adicione essa `tag` no `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no,minimal-ui">
```

- A propriedade `width` controla o tamanho da viewport;
- A propriedade `initial-scale` controla o nível de amplificação;
- As propriedades `maximum-scale`, `minimum-scale`, e `user-scalable` controlam a permissão para o usuário efetuar aumento ou diminuição da página;

Não esqueça de atualizar a página antes de testar.
Espero ter ajudado.

Fontes:
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag
http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp

Comment: Não só ajudou como resolveu o problema, muito obrigado. Aceitarei a resposta assim que o stack permitir

Comment: Já passei pelo mesmo problema. ; )